How to use different serializer for a single class in two different places without SerializersModule?
I have two library methods (I can't change them) that each use serialization, but don't allow me to set SerializersModule. They both take just the SerializationStrategy<T>.
I would like to use different serializer for each of them for a same data class Culprit. How to do it?
I am doing the following, but it's giving me an error as it does not seem to find the contextual serializer I provided for the Culprit.
Minimal example:
// Setup

interface Holders : Any {

}

@Serializable
data class Holder(
    @Contextual
    val culprit: Culprit?,
) : Holders

data class Culprit(
    val a: Int,
    val b: Int,
)

object CulpritStringSerializer : KSerializer<Culprit> {
    // Serializes into a single stirng for example
}

object CulpritClassSerializer : KSerializer<Culprit> {
    // Serializes into full structure with both ints for example
}

// Call site A

val moduleA = SerializersModule {
    contextual(CulpritStringSerializer)
}

fun <T: Holders> mainA(type: KClass<T>, value: T) { // Cannot be inline
    methodA(
        serializer = moduleA.serializer(type, emptyList(), false),
        value = value,
    )
)

// Call site B

@Serializable
data class Wrapper(
   val value: Holder,
)

val moduleB = SerializersModule {
    contextual(CulpritClassSerializer)
}

fun mainB(value: Holder) {
    method(
        serializer = moduleB.serializer<Wrapper>(),
        value = Wrapper(value),
    )
}

It works with Json serializer:
val json = Json {
    serializersModule = SerializersModule {
        contextual(CulpritStringSerializer)
    }
}

fun mainJson(holder: Holder) {
    val serialized = json.encodeToString(holder)
}

